# How will i Insert database record in inner join

Tags: mysql

I created an Update query for two tables with INNER JOIN and its working fine. The code is below.

table 1 = circuiti , table 2 = clienti

```
UPDATE circuiti INNER JOIN clienti ON circuiti.Cod = 
clienti.Cod_ SET es = ?,   
test = ?, type = ?, Note =? 
WHERE circuiti.id= ?"
```

But i want to implement same as this in INSERT query like creating a new record through INNER JOINT of tables. 
thank you.

Comment: can you please better describe the problem so Shadow can answer it?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support the insertion of data into multiple tables in a single sql command. As MySQL documentation on [insert statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) says:

> tbl_name is the table into which rows should be inserted.

You need to issue 2 insert statements after each other. If you include the 2 inserts into a single transaction, then you can commit or rollback both statements as a single unit.

However, if you want to insert into a single table based on values from multiple tables, that can be achieved through an [insert ... select ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) statement, where the select part would have the join of the 2 tables.